# Gmaps.js stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

from one day to another the Gmaps.js Library stopped working... I've created a map with 3 Markers on it and they had InfoWindows and I've added a little routing option in the InfoWindow where you could've typed your address in and Gmaps routed you to that Point.

Now without changing anything in the past 2 weeks, I can't get it to work anymore: The map loads without any problem but when I click on a marker the map kills itself.

Heres the URL: http://gruber.tv/z/#standorte

When I load the map in Firefox I can see many "too much recursion" errors and they all come from Google's main.js

I hope someone can help me!

Best Regards
iDave

Comment: There is console error which says oldUrl is not defined. After solving that does it solve the recursion ?

Comment: no that console error was there before

Comment: But it is now so you need to solve it :)

Comment: I've fixed the error, everything still doesn't work

Comment: if you remove `var startPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng()); var endPos = new google.maps.LatLng(map.markers[id].position.k, map.markers[id].position.D);map.fitLatLngBounds([startPos,endPos]);` just for debugging purpose from routing function, does it solve your issue ?

Comment: I've commented that paragraph out but nothing changed...

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but Micheal Geary solved the mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code that handles the `click` event for each of your markers:

```
map.setCenter( e.position.k, e.position.D );
```

The `setCenter()` method in gmaps takes latitude and longitude arguments. Do `k` and `D` look like sensible names for these? :-)

I suspect that you found these properties by looking around in the developer tools while developing your code, is that right? Set a breakpoint on that line of code and take another look when you get there.

Yikes, there are no `k` or `D` properties there any more. Now it has `A` and `F` properties instead. Well, this won't do.

But do you see the `__proto__` property right below that? Expand that and you'll see the available methods for the `position` object. Note the `lat()` and `lng()` methods there. These make a lot more sense, so try them:

```
map.setCenter( e.position.lat(), e.position.lng() );
```

What happened here: `e.position` is a `LatLng` object from the Google Maps API. The API objects have a number of undocumented internal properties, along with documented properties and methods. `lat()` and `lng()` are the [documented methods to get the latitude and longitude](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLng) from a `LatLng` object. The other properties you discovered are used internally in the API, but they aren't meant for use in your own code. Google runs all their JavaScript API code through a "minifier" that changes internal names arbitrarily to shorten the code but keeps the documented public names intact. So every few weeks when they update their API, any of the undocumented internal names may change.

Comment: Glad to help. I added a note at the end with some more info on what's happening here.